# Validate Extended Validation(EV) of SSL certificate using JSSE

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, jsse

I got list of URLs, and I want to validate their Extended Validation (EV) attribute using JAVA
I can make request and get their certificate, but I am not sure how to validate “Extended Validation” for a given site.

Is there any special value in certificate? Or any attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Extended validation is mostly useful from a user-interface perspective. It's not so useful if your client doesn't have anything in its user interface to display the certificate. These verifications are not integrated by default in the JSSE, possibly because there is little demand for it (lack of Java browsers). (By the way, you should verify the certificate you get upon connection, not check with a first connection and connect with another, just in case).

The specifications are defined by the [CA/browser forum](http://www.cabforum.org/Guidelines_v1_3.pdf).

The OID values and root CA certificate fingerprints are hard-coded into browsers (see [`security/certverifier/ExtendedValidation.cpp` in Firefox, used to be in in `security/manager/ssl/src/nsIdentityChecking.cpp`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/eab4a81e4457/security/certverifier/ExtendedValidation.cpp)). There is also a [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) for reference, although in principle you should check the policy OIDs with each CA.

To analyse the extensions, it might be useful to use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) if `X509Certificate.getExtensionValue()` isn't enough.

One problem you will have to watch out for is that the hard-coded SHA-1 fingerprints of the root CA certificates need to match exactly those certificates in the trust store. Some CAs renew their CA certificates once in a while in the bundles that are shipped with most browsers/OS/JREs: make sure you're using the same.